# How to iterate through folder and add names of files to a single string variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, automation

I'm writing a batch file to automate downloading a game called dwarf fortress with a bunch of other files and images. I have everything working, but now I want to provide the user with the ability to choose a color set from a downloaded folder of .txt files. The trouble is, I want to provide the available color set names based on the file names, so I need to iterate over the folder and get the names of the files (without the .txt extension), and add them to a single string with the format `filename, filename, ... etc`. I am able to iterate over the files, but I cannot figure out how to make that single string. Here's what I have so far (I know it doesn't work):

---

```
set /a colorFileNames=""
for %%f in (%CD%\colors\colors\*) do (
    set %temp%=%%f
    set colorFileNames="%%colorFileNames%%, %temp%:~0,-3"
)
```

---

I then will use the `colorFileNames` in the question for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want to provide the available color set names based on the file names

> I need to iterate over the folder and get the names of the files (without the .txt extension), and add them to a single string with the format filename, filename, ... etc

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set colorFileNames=
for %%f in (%CD%\colors\colors\*) do (
  set _file=%%~nf
  if [!colorFileNames!]==[] (
    set colorFileNames=!_file!
    ) else (
    set colorFileNames=!colorFileNames!, !_file!
    )
)
echo !colorFileNames!
endlocal
```

Example:

```
F:\test>dir /b colors\colors
red.txt
green.txt
blue.txt
sky blue pink.txt

F:\test>test
red, green, blue, sky blue pink
F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [For - Loop through files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)
- [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- [Set - Environment Variable - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Comment: @flüber_ Please ask a new question and make sure you include an example of what you want.

Comment: [new question](https://superuser.com/questions/1540070/how-to-iterate-through-directory-and-concatenate-names-of-folders-into-string)