# How to iterate through directory and concatenate names of folders into string

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, automation

Similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1539452/how-to-iterate-through-folder-and-add-names-of-files-to-a-single-string-variable/1539455#1539455) question, but with folder names instead of with file names. The current code I have for concatenating files is

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set colorFileNames=
for %%f in (%CD%\automation\*) do (
  set _file=%%~nf
  if [!colorFileNames!]==[] (
    set colorFileNames=!_file!
    ) else (
    set colorFileNames=!colorFileNames!, !_file!
    )
)
```

which outputs something like `fileName1, fileName2, ..., fileNameN` but it obviously only works with files. How would I modify it to use folder names instead of file names?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are not here to spoon feed you with answers.

Comment: Okay, good point. I figured it out, and yes, it wasn't difficult.

Comment: Great! ........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed a few things to make it work:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set graphicsSets=
for /D %%f in (%CD%\automation\*) do (
  set _folder=%%~nf
  if [!graphicsSets!]==[] (
    set graphicsSets=!_folder!
    ) else (
    set graphicsSets=!graphicsSets!, !_folder!
    )
)
```

The /D tells the loop to go over directories instead of files, and I replaced what was in the () with just the path to the folder I was looping in. Everything else is the same, so not too difficult of a modification.